# Why array_search does not recognize first item in array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am confused. Why does array_search skip the first element in an array?
in_array returns only booleans, array_search can return any values - is its because of that? For now it makes no sense to me.
Sample code below:

```
<?php

$array = array("Mac", "NT", "Linux");

if (in_array("Mac", $array)) {
    echo "Ok \n";
} else {
    echo "Not ok \n";
}
// output: Ok

if (array_search("Mac", $array)){
     echo "Ok \n";
} else {
    echo "Not ok \n";
}
// output: Not Ok

$arrayForArraySearch = array('', "Mac", "NT", "Linux"); // add first element

if (array_search("Mac", $arrayForArraySearch)){
     echo "Ok \n";
} else {
    echo "Not ok \n";
}
// output: Ok, but it's no longer first item
?>
```

Comment: `array_search()` returns the key if success - i.e. `0` for "Mac", which translates to `false`, so you enter the `else {...}` block.

Comment: @berend Type it out as an answer, so it can be marked.

Answer (score 0):

As in the docs of the array_search function is mentioned, the key of the found element is returned. With your if condition this results in false, because the key of your element "Mac" is `0`.

Change your condition to match not false =>  `if (array_search("Mac", $array) !== false)`

Answer (score 0):

It's because array_search is returning `0` which is the index of "Mac" in the array. If the item is not found in the array, it will return `false`.

Always compare the result to false:

```
if (array_search("Mac", $array) !== false) {
...
}
```